# MySql query wrong result phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

right now I am working on a database where I want to get information over the foreign key.

```
SELECT * FROM Produkt p, Dingseinheit d, Bestellnr b
WHERE p.pID = d.dID = b.bID
AND p.pID = 2;

+-----+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----+------+---------+-----+-----------+
| pID | kategorie  | beschreibung | mengeProKasten | lieferant | x_coord | y_coord | z_coord | beliebtheit | dID | wert | einheit | bID | bestellnr |
+-----+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----+------+---------+-----+-----------+
|   2 | Widerstand | PTC          |            100 | Conrad    |       6 |       0 |       0 |           0 |   2 |  100 | kOhm    |   1 |   1417641 |
+-----+------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----+------+---------+-----+-----------+
```

Scroll all the way right. Why does it show bID and bestellnr.
If you want to know how the tables look. look farther down.

My Database: 
[db design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9483.png)

If I execute this query: [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTluy.png)

I get this result: [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh2Ib.png)

Those are my databases with data:

Produkt database: [Produkt db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQRfb.png)

Dingseinheit database: [Dingseinheit db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x5Y1.png)

Bestellnr database: [Bestellnr db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPXyt.png)

I cant understand why I get the result from the Bestellnr db. I know I could not include this db, but for my future project I would hope to just use one query which shows me all the relevant data eather way which tables I searched.

I hope my problem is understandable if not ask questions.

Also don't mind the german names.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question does not meet the quality guidelines for the site.  You need to include all relevant data directly in your question.  Only use external links for supporting information.

Comment: Hi. You don't want 'a = b = c', it means '(a = b) = c' where a = b will be 0 or 1, you want 'a = b and b = c'. PS See [mcve]. Make your code smaller until you know it is correct, then add what causes a problem & give cut & paste & runnable code with desired output & a clear specification. PS Use text, not links/images, for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
 p.pID = d.dID and p.pID = b.bID
```

Or similar.  What you have does pID = dID, which returns 1 (true), then does 1 = bID.  If you happened to have a row where bID was 0 it would return that too, along with every p and d row combination where they had different IDs.

If there is not a bID for every row, you need a left join.  Rewriting your query with modern SQL syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM Produkt p
JOIN Dingseinheit d ON d.dID=p.pID
LEFT JOIN Bestellnr b ON b.bID=p.pID
WHERE p.pID = 2;
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Produkt p, Dingseinheit d, Bestellnr b
WHERE p.pID = d.dID and p.pID = b.bID
AND p.pID = 2;` returns nothing.

I tried `p.pID = 1` which works fine, but not with 2

Comment: @FlorianDrinkler added to answer

Comment: The second solution with the left join works. Thanks! But is there a better solution that the columns don't even show up. Because right now the cells are NULL but still there. `| pID | kategorie  | beschreibung | mengeProKasten | lieferant | x_coord | y_coord | z_coord | beliebtheit | dID | wert | einheit | bID  | bestellnr |

|   3 | Widerstand | PTC          |             99 | conrad    |      12 |      38 |       3 |           0 |   3 |   38 | hier    | NULL |      NULL |`

Comment: No, there isn't a way to make columns show up or not based on what data is found

Comment: You could make them blank instead, with `select p.*,d.*,coalesce(b.bID,'') as bID,coalesce(b.bestellnr,'') as bestellnr from ...`